# Report builder field with mutiple values separated by a colon

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder

I'm new to report builder and I'm trying to something like this:

Part A:

serialNum,serialNum,serialNum,serialNum,serialNum...

Part B

serialNum,serialNum,serialNum,serialNum,serialNum...

.
.
for all the parts in an invoice

Another choice would be in columns
Part A

```
        serialNum  serialNum  serialNum  serialNum serialNum
        serialNum  serialNum  serialNum  serialNum serialNum
```

Does anybody how to achive this or something similar with Report Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a tablix (white color) with the a row group on part values with two rows.
On the first row you will display the part value

Create a tablix (blue color) with a column group on serial values. Delete the row group and hide the detail.

Now drag the tablix(blue color) with the column group on the 2nd row of the tablix (white color) with the row group.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks , that did the trick

Comment: You are welcome